# Pandas wide_to_long - keep rows with values in i or just one row with blank

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to transform a dataframe into long format, and want to keep the records  following this rule:

(1) if the id has data in the stub - keep all the non-empty "long" records, drop the empty ones
(2) if the id does not have data in any of the stubs, keep only 1 "long" record of it

In other words, for each `id` I need to keep at least one record: 
-exactly one record if the id does not have data in the stub, 
-or as many rows as the `id` has filled in the stub

I am using `wide_to_long` because it allows the use of `stubnames`, which `melt` does not (or at least I could not figure out how to use). This is the sample code (inspired by the official pandas doc on `wide_to_long`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A2001" : {0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c",3:""},
                    "A2002" : {0 : "d", 1 : "e", 2 : "",3:""},
                    "A2003" : {0 : "g", 1 : "h", 2 : "i",3:""},
                    "A2004" : {0 : "j", 1 : "k", 2 : "l",3:""},
                   })

df["id"] = df.index
pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A"], i="id", j="year")
```

The output is:

```
         A
id year   
0  2001  a
1  2001  b
2  2001  c
3  2001   
0  2002  d
1  2002  e
2  2002   
3  2002   
0  2003  g
1  2003  h
2  2003  i
3  2003   
0  2004  j
1  2004  k
2  2004  l
3  2004
```

What I need to achieve:
for ids 0, 1 and 2 I need the rows gone where `["A"]` is blank (or `NaN`); 
for id 3 - I need to keep 1 row (any one row, does not matter which one):

```
         A
id year   
0  2001  a
1  2001  b
2  2001  c
3  2001   
0  2002  d
1  2002  e
0  2003  g
1  2003  h
2  2003  i
0  2004  j
1  2004  k
2  2004  l
```

I tried this:

```
df.dropna(axis=0,how="all",subset=["A"])
```

but it deletes all rows for id 3

**Edit:**

I am also looking for a general solution for this as well, with a list of stubnames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A2001" : {0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "",3:""},
                    "A2002" : {0 : "d", 1 : "e", 2 : "test",3:""},
                    "A2003" : {0 : "g", 1 : "h", 2 : "i",3:""},
                    "A2004" : {0 : "j", 1 : "k", 2 : "l",3:""},
                    "B2001" : {0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "",3:""},
                    "B2002" : {0 : "d", 1 : "e", 2 : "",3:""},
                    "B2003" : {0 : "g", 1 : "h", 2 : "i",3:""},
                    "B2004" : {0 : "j", 1 : "k", 2 : "l",3:""},
                   })

pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A","B"], i="id", j="year")
```

I need to delete rows where both A and B columns are empty, but still keep at least 1 record for each `id` (and exactly one record if A and B are both blanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask to NaN before you `wide_to_long` then `dropna` using the threshold.

`m` checks if every stub column is empty for a row. Replace either all, or all but one, `''` with NaN, based on `m`. This allows us to keep exactly one row in the result when all stubs are missing:

If you change the `suffix` or `sep` parameters in `wide_to_long`, you will need to adjust the creation of `scols` accordingly.

```
stubs = ['A', 'B']
scols = df.columns[df.columns.str.split('[0-9]+').str[0].isin(stubs)]  #Mimic stubs
m = df.loc[:, scols].eq('').all(1)

df.loc[~m, scols] = df.loc[~m, scols].replace('', np.NaN)
df.loc[m, scols[1:]] = np.NaN

(pd.wide_to_long(df.assign(id=df.index), stubnames=stubs, i="id", j="year")
   .dropna(thresh=1)
   .replace(np.NaN, '')  #Or perhaps the empty to NaN
)
```

#### Output:

```
            A  B
id year         
0  2001     a  a
1  2001     b  b
3  2001         
0  2002     d  d
1  2002     e  e
2  2002  test   
0  2003     g  g
1  2003     h  h
2  2003     i  i
0  2004     j  j
1  2004     k  k
2  2004     l  l
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow your condition and logic

```
df["id"] = df.index
s=pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A"], i="id", j="year")
s=s.groupby(level=0).A.apply(lambda x : x.head(1) if (x=='').all() else x[x!='']).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
s.sort_index(level=1)

Out[137]: 
id  year
0   2001    a
1   2001    b
2   2001    c
3   2001     
0   2002    d
1   2002    e
0   2003    g
1   2003    h
2   2003    i
0   2004    j
1   2004    k
2   2004    l
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: What if instead of the single-column stub I have a list of them ? 
`pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A","B","C"], i="id", j="year")`
Can your example be generalized ?

Comment: @horace_vr just need to group by two level of index then.:-)

Comment: how can I do that ? ;)

Comment: @horace_vr `s=pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A","B"], i="id", j="year").stack();s=s.groupby(level=[0,2]).A.apply(lambda x : x.head(1) if (x=='').all() else x[x!='']).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)`

Comment: `'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'A'`. Probably because you are stacking it...?

Comment: @horace_vr remove A `s=s.groupby(level=[0,2]).apply(lambda x : x.head(1) if (x=='').all() else x[x!='']).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)`

Comment: still got 2 empty records for id 3, because of  the A/B column:

 `A  3   2001  A        

B  3   2001  B        `

Comment: @horace_vr if you have following question , please either update your question or open a new question .

Comment: edited with the generalised problem; sorry, and thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194127/discussion-between-horace-vr-and-wenyoben).

Answer (score 1):

#### Similar to [WeNYoBen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363694/2336654)

```
s = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["A"], i="id", j="year")

def f(d):
    m = d.A.eq('')
    return d.head(1) if m.all() else d[~m]

t = pd.concat([f(d) for _, d in s.groupby('id')])

t.loc[[*filter(t.index.__contains__, s.index)]]

         A
id year   
0  2001  a
1  2001  b
2  2001  c
3  2001   
0  2002  d
1  2002  e
0  2003  g
1  2003  h
2  2003  i
0  2004  j
1  2004  k
2  2004  l
```